# Column not found when reading csv data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm using the following code to try and extract the 'Line' column of the kaggle south park conversation data. (https://www.kaggle.com/tovarischsukhov/southparklines/data#)

```
csv_read = pd.read_csv("southparkdata.csv", usecols=['Line'], engine='python', error_bad_lines=False, sep='\n')
```

I'm getting the error that the column isn't found. However when I print the columns I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are the first lines from the file `All-seasons.csv` from the Kaggle link you have posted, including the header:

```
Season,Episode,Character,Line
10,1,Stan,"You guys, you guys! Chef is going away. 
"
10,1,Kyle,"Going away? For how long?
"
10,1,Stan,"Forever.
"
10,1,Chef,"I'm sorry boys.
"
10,1,Stan,"Chef said he's been bored, so he joining a group called the Super Adventure Club. 
"
```

from which it is apparent that the separator is not `\n`, but comma.

So, change your reading command to use `sep=','` instead of `sep='\n'`, and you should be fine (or you could omit the `sep` argument altogether, since the default value is indeed `','` - check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You are using sep=**'\n'**, please, check this (probably sep=',', sep=';', or sep='\t').
If it doesn't work, please provide few lines of the file.